# How initialize part of form in redux-form

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

there is possible to initialize some parts of form in redux form ?

For example:

I want to initializa whole form.

For a while I want join other component to form and initialize its data.

How I should do it ?

Additionally I make a temporary solution for taking old initialData and add new values inside an reinitialize whole form with that whole object with that new data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and set initialvalues from state

http://redux-form.com/7.0.1/examples/initializeFromState/

Comment: I saw it. But there I cant initialize part of form, I have to init whole form. I just want to init single form element.

Comment: some more details would be great. What kind of inputs are you looking to prefill?